# How to play several Videos in sequence way?

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I am trying to make one app to play several videos sequentially, for it, I have seen the Katura HTML5 Video Player to do it and I would like to ask you if it is Samsung SDK compatible or it is not which HTML5 Video Player is Samsung SDK compatible?

Thanks in advance

Alejandro

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this would be to create an array with the videos to play and utilize the OnRenderingComplete callback in the player plugin to play the next video in the array when the current video finishes. Roughly something like:

```
var videos = ["url1", "url2"];
function playNext() {
  if (videos.length > 0) {
    url = videos.shift();
    player.Play(url);
  } else {
    //Playlist is over
  }
}

player.OnRenderingComplete = 'playNext';
```